# Unable to use amlcurran.showcaseview library in android studio

Tags: android, showcaseview

I am trying to use amlcurran/showcaseview library and i am following [this](https://indiependev.wordpress.com/2014/12/30/using-showcaseview-on-android/) tutorial, but i am unable tor resolve the library:

```
Error:(29, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.0.0
```

Here is my build.gradle(project) file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.wolverine.showcasetutorial"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com" }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.0.0'
}
```

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

add this your manifest file

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview"/>
```